# Best approach to create an object that has an array of instances of another class as a property in cocoa

Tags: objective-c, arrays, cocoa

I have two classes in my program, one of them has an array of another one `(@property)`.
For example a classroom that has an array of students.
What's the difference between these approaches?

1. create an `instance method` for the the array creation when I'm `init`ing the first  object
2. create a `class method` in second class .h file that creates the array containing `instancetype` instances
3. any other approach

note: I do not need instance of second class individually, they have meaning when they are properties of first class.

P.S. I could not set a shorter title for this. If you think of sth better please do that :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With 1) The owner of the classroom, such as a school, would have to have a reference the students so that when it instantiated the classroom it could pass the array of students to the classroom.  This would be a problem if you wanted to instantiate the classroom, but don't know what the students are yet.  But is good if you know all of the students at the instantiate of the classroom, and also don't plan on the students ever changing

With 2) The classroom can be instantiated first, and then later the school can call `addStudents` or whatever method is sitting inside of the classroom class-- as the school becomes aware of the students.

Another solution would to just have your classroom class have a public `NSArray` property.  Then the school can `addObject` and `removeObject` whenever; effectively giving you full control of the classroom's students at all times